# PhantomJS 2: Detecting click that did not trigger an event

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using **PhantomJS 2** to click on elements of a page. However, I don't know whether a click on these elements will trigger an event (e.g. a page load).

I'd like to be able to handle both cases:

1. When a click on an element triggers a page load then I'd like to wait until the new page has been loaded.
2. When a click does not trigger an event, I'd like to be able to recognize that (without having to wait for a long timeout).

In **PhantomJS 1**, I could simply make use of a closure like this:

```
function click(page, elem, callback) {
  var loading = false;

  page.set('onLoadStarted', function() {
    loading = true;
  });

  page.set('onLoadFinished', function() {
    callback('click triggered page load');
  });

  triggerClick(page, elem);

  setTimeout(function() {
    if ( ! loading) {
      callback('click did not trigger page load');
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Here I'm closing over the `loading` variable which acts as a "communication channel" between the event handlers and the function in `setTimeout`.

1. In case the click triggers a page load, the `onLoadFinished` handler will call the callback after the page has been loaded.
2. In case the click does not trigger a page load, the function in `setTimeout` will call the callback after just 100ms (which is acceptable).

This code has been working well under PhantomJS 1.

Under PhantomJS 2 unfortunately, the event handlers for the `onLoadStarted` and `onLoadFinished` can't access the `loading` variable anymore (i.e. they don't work as closures anymore as it seems).

So now I'm wondering how I can achieve the same behavior in PhantomJS 2. Any ideas?

**PS**: I'm aware that I have to install the event handlers via `page.property(...)` in PhantomJS 2 instead of using `page.set(...)` like in PhantomJS 1.

**Edit**: I'm using the node package phantom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) as a bridge between node & phantomjs.

Comment: There is no `page.set` in PhantomJS (1 or 2). Are you using some kind of bridge between node.js and PhantomJS?

Comment: Ah, yes indeed - I'm using the node package phantom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom). Obviously forgot to mention that ;) . However, I'm wondering about in which way that might be involved in a solution to my problem described above... is that actually an issue with this node bridge instead of with phantomjs itself?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was in fact to abandon the node bridge and instead use pure phantomjs. This results in the following corresponding code to work like a charm, even with **PhantomJS 2**:

```
function click(page, elem, callback) {
  var loading = false;

  page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loading = true;
  };

  page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    callback('click triggered page load');
  };

  triggerClick(page, elem);

  setTimeout(function() {
    if ( ! loading) {
      callback('click did not trigger page load');
    }
  }, 100);
}
```